# Вылетает вторая активность приложения java

Tags: java, android

Вылетает приложение при запуске второй активность в java. При этом код второй активности

```
package com.example.arseny.myapplication;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

public class Activity_Two extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String licence = getStringFromRawResource(getInputSteam(R.raw.licence));
        TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        result.setText(licence);
    }

    @NonNull
    private String getStringFromRawResource(InputStream inputStream) {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                writer.write(line);
                writer.append("\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return writer.toString();
    }
    private  InputStream getInputSteam(int rawId) {
        return getResources().openRawResource(rawId);
    }
}
```

выдает вот такую ошибку в Android monitor:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.arseny.myapplication, PID: 26546

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.arseny.myapplication/com.example.arseny.myapplication.Activity_Two}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5305)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at com.example.arseny.myapplication.Activity_Two.onCreate(Activity_Two.java:24)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2280)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5305)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Вообще в первой активности находится просто одна кнопка по нажатию на которую выкидывает на вторую активность. А во второй активности просто одно текстовое поле в которое вывожу txt файл. По тексту ошибки догадываюсь, что ошибка где-то здесь

```
String licence = getStringFromRawResource(getInputSteam(R.raw.licence));
            TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            result.setText(licence);
```

Но вот что там не так и как это устранить...

Кстати заметил закономерность, что при запуске этого же кода в проекте без второй активности все отлично работает!

Помогите мне пожалуйста разобраться с этим!

main_activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.arseny.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="587dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:onClick="button"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_two

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.arseny.myapplication.Activity_Two">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="412dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="91dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="57dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.25" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `findViewById` не находит элемент с таким id. Соответственно, в `result` оказывается `null`, а у `null` метод вызвать нельзя.

Comment: А как это исправить? Не очень понимаю

Comment: Файл разметки `activity_main.xml` в вопрос добавьте, пожалуйста

Comment: Вот. Добавил оба на всякий случай

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка по факту кроется почти в том месте, которое Вы сами нашли:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //только вот здесь должно быть activity_two

    String licence = getStringFromRawResource(getInputSteam(R.raw.licence));
    TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    result.setText(licence);
}
```

То есть единственное исправление:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);
```

Comment: Ой не заметил этого. А так все элементарно оказалось, спасибо огромное вам!